# Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: spring, ant, junit

When i run junit test cases, getting following error:

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'CacheRegionManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bgc/ecm/core/caching/cacheRegionManager-ctx.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'appRoot'

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'CacheRegionManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bgc/ecm/core/caching/cacheRegionManager-ctx.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'appRoot'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:268)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)
```

cacheRegionManager-ctx.xml file:

```
<bean id="CacheRegionManagerFactory" class="com.bgc.ecm.core.caching.CacheRegionManagerFactory">
          <property name="diskStoreCachePath" value="${diskStoreCacheRootPath}/${appRoot}/was/var/elnino/${appName}/${cloneNumber}"/>
        <property name="defaultRegion" ref="DefaultRegion"/>
        <property name="regionInfos" ref="CustomRegions"/>                
    </bean>
```

propertyContext.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder 
               location="classpath:/property/globalContext.properties,     
                       classpath:/property/globalContext-${app.env}.properties,
                       classpath:/property/globalContext-${app.env}-${app.module}.properties,    
                       classpath:/property/applicationContext.properties,
                       classpath:/property/applicationContext-${app.module}.properties,         
                       classpath:/property/applicationContext-${app.env}.properties,           
                       classpath:/property/applicationContext-${app.env}-${app.module}.properties"/>
```

and applicationContext-DEV-FNT.properties contains:

```
appName=bgc-elnino-core-cluster
appRoot=ecm
cloneNumber=1
site=elnino-core
```

Junit target:

```
<target name="junit" depends="init-junit">
    <copy todir="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}/" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${COMP_TESTCONFIG_DIR}">
            <exclude name="*.properties.template" />
        </fileset>
    </copy> 
    <junit printsummary="on" fork="yes" forkmode="perBatch" haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="junit.failure" showoutput="false">           
        <classpath>
            <path refid="CLASSPATH_JUNIT"/>             
        </classpath>            
        <batchtest fork="no"  todir="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}">
           <fileset dir="${COMP_TEST_SRC}" erroronmissingdir="false">                             
              <include name="**/*Test.java" />
                  <include name="**/Test*.java" />                          
           </fileset>              
        </batchtest>
        <formatter type="xml" />
    </junit>    
    <junitreport todir="${JUNIT_REPORT}">
        <fileset dir="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />           
        </fileset>       
        <report format="frames" todir="${JUNIT_REPORT}"/>       
    </junitreport>      
    <delete dir="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}" />  

</target>
```

> env variable is:

```
public final void setupEnvironmentPropertiesIfNeeded()
{
    String address = (new StringBuilder()).append("@").append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).toString();
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(System.getProperty("app.env")))
    {
        LOG.info((new StringBuilder()).append(address).append(" Environment property app.env will be set to DEV").toString());
        System.setProperty("app.env", "DEV");
    } else
    {
        LOG.info((new StringBuilder()).append(address).append(" Environment property app.env already set to:'").append(System.getProperty("app.env")).append("'").toString());
    }
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(System.getProperty("app.module")))
    {
        LOG.info((new StringBuilder()).append(address).append(" Environment property app.module will be set to FNT").toString());
        System.setProperty("app.module", "FNT");
    } else
    {
        LOG.info((new StringBuilder()).append(address).append(" Environment property app.module already set to:'").append(System.getProperty("app.module")).append("'").toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: how are your ${app.env} and ${app.module} properties resolved?

Comment: Please post the Junit file, I guess the problem is that the propertyContext.xml is not loaded.

Comment: how is ${app.env}, ${app.module} populated?

Comment: Are you sure that specified applicationContext-DEV-FNT.properties is getting loaded? Try hard code the propery file list to include that file.

Comment: @kasim: did you test taht the problem is only for appRoot, but not for the other properties: appName, cloneNumber, site?

Comment: @kasim: I did not meant the junit target, I meant the Junit file, to see how spring context is loaded (the Annotation).

Comment: @ Michael Wiles,  applicationContext-DEV-FNT.properties, was loaded, but entry was missing.

Comment: Do you have multiple profiles may be reused context: property-placeholder, you need to add the attribute ignore-unresolvable = "true" can be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue can be solved by passing "-DappRoot=ECM" parameter and other required parameters.

Comment: But that is just loading a property from the properties file at the command line. What about the other properties that are in the `applicationContext-DEV-FNT.properties` file?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your properties file is not getting loaded. Try explicitly loading the properties file using:

```
<property file="applicationContext-DEV-FNT.properties" />
```